# Fade in and fade out object on a specific time

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

```
int state = 1;
bool turbines_visible = true;

// move the hot air balloon up
// make the square go up
void update(int value) {
    // 1 : move up
    if (state == 1) {
        squareY += 1.0f;
        if (squareY > 650.0) {
            state = 2;
            squareX = -400.0f;
            squareY = 200.0f;
        }
    }
    // 2 : move right
    else if (state == 2) {
        squareX += 1.0f;
        if (squareX > 500.0) {
            state = 3;
            squareX = 0.0f;
            squareY = 600.0f;
        }
    }
    // 3 : move down
    else if (state == 3) {
        squareY -= 1.0f;
        if (squareY < 0.0) {
            state = 0;
        }
    }
    glutTimerFunc(25, update, 0);
    turbines_visible = !turbines_visible;
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    switch (state) {
    case 0:
        drawBackground1();
        break;
    case 1:
        drawBackground1();
        break;
    case 2:
        drawBackground2();
        break;
    case 3:
        drawBackground1();
        break;
    }
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(squareX, squareY, squareZ);
    // display spray
    drawSpray();
    // display hot air balloon
    drawAirBalloon();
    glPopMatrix();  
    if (turbines_visible) {
        // display first (left) wind turbine
        drawLeftTurbine();
        // display first (right) wind turbine
        drawRightTurbine();
    }
    // display rain
    drawRain();
    calcFPS();
    counter++;
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

The hot air balloon travels up perfectly fine, but the wind turbines keep faded in and out really fast, which is what I don't want. I want it to be visible in the first scene, invisible in the second scene, and visible again in the third scene. I know that the problem is with the `glutTimerFunc` code because it is using 25 milliseconds, but I need it for my hot air balloon. I would appreciate if someone could help me solve this problem.

[Click here to see the full code](http://cpp.sh/4jwyn)

**Scene 1**

[image]

[Click here to see GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/Ca6Tu2vZT75la5rplF/giphy.gif)

**Scene 2**

[image]

[Click here to see GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/dCB0Tz02gfW4d5F0Vl/giphy.gif)

**Scene 3**

[image]

[Click here to see GIF](https://media.giphy.com/media/7FheuCP7xH5MqcV6mf/giphy.gif)

Comment: `turbines_visible = !turbines_visible;` should be place when change scene, not `update`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it to be visible in the first scene, invisible in the second scene, and visible again in the third scene.

The condition for `turbines_visible` has to be

<s>`turbines_visible = !turbines_visible;`</s>
`turbines_visible = state != 2;`